# Draw line (or anything else) in the CustomAdpter item

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw, custom-adapter

I have custom Adapter in my app and I need to draw simple line in each ListView item, based on some numbers.

I have read many related tutorials but I still have no idea how do I implement it in the right way. I am new to Android and Java but I seem to understand everything about Android but painting/drawing. Could anyone suggest some guidance for me to get it.

EDIT:

Here is some my code I am using now:

In the one-item-layout (row.xml) I have ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In my custom adapter I have this:

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView{

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 20, 20, p);

    }

}
```

What I have trouble with is how to put my custom view in the image view (or any other container).

Comment: Can you give some more details. How do the numbers determine the lines? Does the way the line is drawn between each listview item change based on which item it is?

Comment: Also if you could post some code of what you're currently doing I could help more.

Comment: Added some code to the post.
Actually I have custom class with array field, so ideally I want to draw line based on these numbers. But I need to understand how to draw in my view at all (because I don't now).

Comment: will you custom view always be the same size and just have different numbers of lines?

Comment: Let's say it is simlest possible chart based on few numbers(my Class array attribute which are going to be coordinates). So it will be same size for each list, with different lines inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView{

private Paint mPaint;
private float cx, cy;
private int size; 

public MyImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
  mPaint = new Paint();
  mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, size, size, mPaint);

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    cx = w/2;
    cy = h/2;
    ///calculate the size of the view here. 
    size = Math.min(w, h);
}



  @Override
   protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `View` to your layout to draw the line and change it's colour/width from the adapter.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and in the adapter

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    private Context context;

    MyAdapter(Context context, Integer[] numbers) {
        super(context, R.layout.your_layout, numbers);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.lineView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chart);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = convertView.getTag();
        }

        int number = getItem(position);

        // Calculate width based on your number. Must be in px
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = holder.lineView.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = calculatedWidth;

        // Calculate color based on your number
        int color = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
        holder.lineView.setBackroundColor(color);
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        View lineView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this bot now I am getting NullPointer error.
And I still do not get how drawing works in this case, feel myself like an idiot.

Comment: @Vla It seems you want to draw sloped lines. This approach won't work for that case. Try Developer Pauls's answer.